# How to plot properly the disconnected regions if using the option Joined->True?

Tags: plotting, data

Consider the following domain:

```
reg = RegionPlot[(x^2 + y^2) <= 1 || 2 <= (x^3 + y^2) <= 5, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -5, 5}];
sens = {#[[1]], #[[2]]} & /@ 
   Partition[Flatten[Cases[Normal@reg, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]], 2];
```

Let us assume that `sens` is pre-generated. I would like to plot the resulting domain:

```
ListPlot[sens, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

You may notice a straight line joining the two disconnected regions. Could you please tell me how to avoid their joining for this and other cases?

Comment: Do not use `Flatten`, `ListPlot[Cases[Normal@reg, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity], Joined -> True]`

Comment: alternatively, you can always separate your OR conditions in two plots before you break them. But @cvgmt's answer is by far better!

Comment: @cvgmt I think your comment merits an answer despite the "triviality" of the solution.

Comment: @cvgmt : thanks! Would it be possible to export/import the unflattened object as e.g., `Table`, or some special format would be needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can remove `Flatten` and export the two groups of points to `xls` with two sheets for further use.

```
Clear[reg,sens];
reg = RegionPlot[(x^2 + y^2) <= 1 || 2 <= (x^3 + y^2) <= 5, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -5, 5}];
sens = Cases[Normal@reg, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
Export["test.xls", sens];
SystemOpen["test.xls"]
data = Import["test.xls"];
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Graphics[{Line@data}]
```

[image]